# Decouple a system of two second order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have a system of second-order differential equations that I want to decouple. they are,

$\ddot{x} = \frac{\omega_1^2}{2} x + \omega_2 \dot{y}$

and

$\ddot{y} = \frac{\omega_1^2}{2} y - \omega_2 \dot{x}$

I am thinking that I should use some transformation, but it just isn't clear in my head yet!

Thanks!

Comment: The fastest way to solve this differential system is to note that the complex-valued function $z=x+iy$ solves $$z''=\frac{\omega_1^2}2z-i\omega_2z',$$ and to identify $z$.

Comment: I was thinking of something similar, a Transformation like $M = \binom{u}{v}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\binom{x - iy}{y-ix}\Rightarrow M^{-1}=\binom{x}{y}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\binom{u + iv}{v+iu}$

Comment: @Did Could you expand more on your answer, or point me to the right resources? Thanks!!

Comment: Could you expand more on the specific problem you have, understanding my comment? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps I am being a little stupid, but I can't quite see the reasoning why you can choose the complex-valued function you suggest? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you try to write down $z''$, assuming that $z=x+iy$? Please show the result.

Comment: Yes, I mean if I use your approach I get the expected results for the frequency. So your approach is definitely correct!

What I mean is; I can't arrive at the differential equation you suggest to me, and how I can use $z = x + iy$ and relate it to the terms in my differential equations.

Comment: See previous comment: if $z=x+iy$ then $z''=x''+iy''=\ldots$ (but it is sweet of you to state that "(my) approach is definitely correct"...).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40390/discussion-between-quantumpenguin-and-did).

Comment: Let us not. $ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Laplace transform:

- $$x''(t)=\frac{\omega_1^2}{2}\cdot x(t)+\omega_2y'(t)\Longleftrightarrow s^2x(s)-sx(0)-x'(0)=\frac{\omega_1^2}{2}\cdot x(s)+\omega_2\left[sy(s)-y(0)\right]$$
- $$y''(t)=\frac{\omega_1^2}{2}\cdot y(t)-\omega_2x'(t)\Longleftrightarrow s^2y(s)-sy(0)-y'(0)=\frac{\omega_1^2}{2}\cdot y(s)-\omega_2\left[sx(s)-x(0)\right]$$

Now, we can find that:

- $$x(s)=\frac{2\left(sx(0)+x'(0)-\omega_2y(0)+\omega_2y(s)s\right)}{2s^2-\omega_1^2}$$
- $$y(s)=\frac{2\left(sy(0)+y'(0)-\omega_2x(0)+\omega_2x(s)s\right)}{2s^2-\omega_1^2}$$

Substitute them into each other and solve it with inverse Laplace transform.

Comment: Thanks for this, I didn't know about this technique. I will try it! Cheers!

Comment: @QuantumPenguin You're welcome, I'm glad that I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Differentiate the first wrt $t$ to gain an expression for $\ddot y$:

$\dddot{x} = \frac{\omega_1^2}{2} \dot x + \omega_2 \ddot{y}$

Substitute $\ddot{y} = \frac{\omega_1^2}{2} y - \omega_2 \dot{x}$ to get:

$\dddot{x} = \frac{\omega_1^2}{2} \dot x + \frac{\omega_1^2 \omega_2}{2} y - \omega_2^2 \dot{x}$

Rearrange: $\frac{\omega_1^2 \omega_2}{2} y =\dddot{x} - \frac{\omega_1^2}{2} \dot x + \omega_2^2 \dot{x}$

Differentiate: $\frac{\omega_1^2 \omega_2}{2} \dot y =\ddddot{x} + \frac{2\omega_2^2 -\omega_1^2}{2} \ddot x$

Recall that $\ddot{x} = \frac{\omega_1^2}{2} x + \omega_2 \dot{y} \Rightarrow  \omega_2 \dot{y}=\ddot{x} - \frac{\omega_1^2}{2} x$

Thus: $\frac{\omega_1^2}{2} \left (\ddot{x} - \frac{\omega_1^2}{2} x \right ) =\ddddot{x} + \frac{2\omega_2^2 -\omega_1^2}{2} \ddot x$

... which becomes $\ddddot{x} + \frac{2\omega_2^2 -\omega_1^2}{2} \ddot x -  \frac{\omega_1^2}{2} \left (\ddot{x} - \frac{\omega_1^2}{2} x \right )=0 $

or $\ddddot{x} + \left(\omega_2^2 -\omega_1^2 \right ) \ddot x -  \frac{\omega_1^4}{2}x =0 $

Auxiliary equation $\lambda^4+p\lambda^2-q=0$ where $p=\left(\omega_2^2 -\omega_1^2 \right )$ and $q=\omega_1^4$

$\lambda^2={-p+\sqrt{p^2+4q} \over 2}$ or $\lambda^2={-p-\sqrt{p^2+4q} \over 2}$

$\lambda_1=\sqrt{{-p+\sqrt{p^2+4q} \over 2}}$

$\lambda_2=-\sqrt{{-p+\sqrt{p^2+4q} \over 2}}$

$\lambda_3=\sqrt{{-p-\sqrt{p^2+4q} \over 2}}$

$\lambda_4=-\sqrt{{-p-\sqrt{p^2+4q} \over 2}}$

Comment: But then I am left with a term in $\dddot{x}$?

Comment: Cool! Auxiliary equation will be a cubic. Does that really cause a problem?

Comment: It's more that I want to decouple these equations such that I can solve them separately and extract the frequencies for the equations in terms of $\ddot{x}$ and $\ddot{y}$ respectively. So I would have say $\omega_{a}$ and $\omega_{b}$ which would both have a dependency on $\omega_{1}$ and $\omega_{2}$. I hope that makes sense?