Best way to decouple a system of second-order ODE
Consider if there is some position vector $\mathbf{r}=(x,y,0)$, with its velocity given by the pointwise derivative. For some external frequency vector $\boldsymbol{\Omega}=(0,0,\Omega)$, suppose the Lagrangian is given by
$$\mathscr{L}=\frac{1}{2}|\dot{\mathbf{r}}|^2+\boldsymbol{\Omega}\cdot(\mathbf{r}\times\dot{\mathbf{r}})+\frac{1}{2}\omega_0^2|\mathbf{r}|^2.\tag{1}$$
So the Lagrangian can then be expressed as
$$\mathscr{L}=\frac{1}{2}(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2)+(x\dot{y}-y\dot{x})\Omega+\frac{1}{2}\omega_0^2(x^2+y^2).\tag{2} $$
And by the First Euler-Lagrange Equation, that is,
$$\partial_{q^i}\mathscr{L}-\frac{d \partial_{\dot{q}^i}\mathscr{L}}{dt}=0\tag{3} $$
it turns out the equations of motion are
$$x''(t)=2y'(t)\Omega +\omega_0^2 x(t)$$
$$y''(t) = -2x'(t)\Omega+\omega_0^2 y(t).\tag{4}$$
I am lost at how to decouple these equations to solve for the equations of motion in $x(t)$ and $y(t)$. One approach I tried was a Laplace transform, but this involved a lot of constants to determine when I was inverse transforming. I also tried letting $z=x+iy$, noting that this is a solution to the equation $$z''(t)=\Omega z(t)-i\omega_0^2 z'(t).$$ This resulted in what I suspect is too simple an answer; namely, that $$x''+iy''=\Omega x+\Omega iy-i\omega_0^2x'+\omega_0^2y',$$ then by taking the real part (this is a physical system), $x''(t)=\Omega x$ and $y''(t)=\omega_0^2 y'(t).$ The problem at hand also mentions that there is a stability condition $$\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{r'}=0\iff \Omega^2>\omega^2.$$ I am not even sure where the $\Omega^2$ comes in. If anyone can give some tips, I'd appreciate it!

Similar question.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1801940/decouple-a-system-of-two-second-order-differential-equations

Let $x' = X, y' = Y$ then try to diagonalise the corresponding matrix on the RHS.

@MatthewCassell the issue with this is, I get a 2x2 matrix of the functions $X, Y, x$. I thought this is usually with the constants.

^ and $y$ as well

Your complexified equation should be $z''=i\Omega z'+\omega_0^2z$. Everything below that is wrong. Especially if you separate real and imaginary parts, you should get back the original equations.

Are you sure that the last term is added and not subtracted? An oscillator with rotation is more interesting than a repelling system with rotation.

@LutzLehmann unfortunately I am sure

I ask because $\omega$ is usually used for frequencies, exponential rates get $k$ or $\beta$ or so. So one would expect an equation for an oscillation if $\Omega=0$.

@LutzLehmann I also think that the choice of notation is odd, it isn't mine. If by $\beta$ you mean something like the damping coefficient, then yes. Here, $\Omega$ is some applied frequency, often denoted $\omega$, while $\omega_0$ is the natrual frequency (the '$\sqrt{k/m}$' one)

But that is the problem, $\omega_0$ is not connected to any oscillation (in real time), it is not a frequency, natural or otherwise. // It is sometimes easy to mix up the Lagrangian and Hamiltonian.

@LutzLehmann I now understand your point, at least regarding the Lagrangian vs Hamiltonian. But I reiterate this is the problem given, I didn’t derive the Lagrangian. I don’t know why the last term is added. As for \omega_0, whether it “is” or “isn’t,” it’s common in physics for that quantity to be called the “natural frequency” of oscillation (“angular frequency,” to be strict)

You should concentrate on correcting your equation for $z$. The decoupling is then just eliminating the first-order term via a factor. // $u''-k^2u=0$ has basis solution $u=Ae^{kt}+Be^{-kt}$. There is no oscillation, no repeating or periodic motion. $k$ is no frequency.

@LutzLehmann I guess I am still lost as to how the first order term can be eliminated. Using z=x+iy, wouldn’t $x’’=-y’+k^2x$, using $z’’=i\Omega z’ + \omega_0^2 z$?

Adding both equations as real and imaginary part gives
$$
z''=x''+iy''=\Omega(y'-ix')+\omega_0^2(x+iy)
\\=-i\Omega z'+\omega_0^2z
$$
The term coupling the real and imaginary parts is the first-order one. There are standard methods to eliminate this. Consider $w=e^{i\Omega t/2}z$. Then
$$
w'=e^{i\Omega t/2}(z'+i(\Omega/2)z)\\
w''=e^{i\Omega t/2}(z''+i\Omega z'-(\Omega^2/4)z)\\
$$
Inserting the differential equation gives
$$
w''=(\omega_0^2-\Omega^2/4)w
$$
As the factor on the right side is real, this decouples the equations for the real and imaginary part of $w$.
